# How to edit a MonoBehaviour's properties on a prefab in the UnityEditor from Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Assume I have a simple `MonoBehaviour`

```
public class FooScript : MonoBehaviour {
  public int someValue = 0;
}
```

I make GameObject, attach a `FooScript`. I make a prefab from that and delete in instance in the scene.

In the editor I can select the prefab in the project and I can edit `someValue`.

Assuming I know the path to the prefab how I can make an edit time script that makes edits to the `FooScript` instance inside the prefab?

What've tried

```
GameObject prefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(pathToPrefab);
GameObject root = ???? // WHAT DO I CALL HERE!?
FooScript fooScript = root.GetComponent<FooScript>();
fooScript.someValue = 789;
```

Actually in that case `prefab` is null

If switch to

```
Object prefab = AssetDatabase.LoadMainAssetAtPath(prefabPath);                 
GameObject root = prefab as GameObject;
```

`prefab` is not null but `root` is

Next I tried this

```
Object[] objs = AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath(prefabPath);
foreach (var o in obs)
{
   Debug.Log("    type:" + (o.GetType().Name));
}
```

That prints

```
type: GameObject
type: Transform
type: FooScript
```

But using that is a hacky solution as I'd have to try every GameObject and or FooScript. I means I suppose as a pragmatic solution it might work but it feels like adding technical debt I'll have to fix later

Other things I've tried is creating a new prefab with a new GameObject and a new FooScript and calling `PrefabUtility.ReplacePrefab`

```
GameObject newGameObject = new GameObject();
FooScript fooScript = newGameObject.AddComponent<FooScript>();
fooScript.someValue = 789;

Object prefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(prefabPath);
PrefabUtility.ReplacePrefab(newGameObject, prefab, ReplacePrefabOptions.ConnectToPrefab);

GameObject.Destory(newGameObject); // don't want this in the scene
```

But that's not working for me. The values in the prefab get replaced but all instances in the scene get disconnected.

To reiterate. I'm NOT trying to edit an instance of a prefab. I'm trying to edit the prefab itself from a script at edit time.

Comment: Did you try via https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.html ?

Comment: Yes, sorry. `Asset.` was a typo. updated the question

Comment: [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/assetdatabase-loadassetatpath-not-working.134913/) they suggest to use [Resources.LoadAssetAtPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAssetAtPath.html) but the docs say it's depricated

Comment: @gman can you say what the `prefab.GetType ().Name;` says.

Comment: It prints `Object`

Comment: Calling `AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetAtPath` hackily seems like it might work but ugh :(

Comment: the reason your second solution probably doesn't work is because of `Object prefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(prefabPath);` maybe if you there use `Object` instead of `GameObject` it won't remove the prefab links?

Comment: Sigh!!! That was it. And it comes back as type = GameObject. BUG!!! Thanks! If you want to put that in an answer that getting a prefab as GameObject fails but getting it as Object works even though it's a GameObject I'll be happy to mark it

Comment: added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 // this fails
 GameObject prefab = 
    AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(pathToPrefab));

 // this fails
 GameObject prefab = 
    AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(pathToPrefab, typeof(GameObject));  

 // this succeeds
 GameObject prefab = 
    AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(pathToPrefab, typeof(Object)) as GameObject;
```

Comment: you reason on the second solution doesn't make sense to me. Object is just a case to base class. Nothing changes.

Comment: I thought because `Object prefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(prefabPath);` fails the that the `PrefabUtility.ReplacePrefab` would be called with a `null`. But then the prefab wouldn't be replaced so it indeed doesn't make complete sense. Still happy there is a solution by miscommunication then :)

Comment: Oh yea, I should try using Replace again. Not entirely sure that's what I want but I'll give it a try. [See new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787298/how-to-update-a-prefab-property-from-editor-script-and-have-the-instances-get-th) :P   Maybe the answer is to replace the prefab? Although that would actually suck because I'd have to copy all the properties from the old prefab to the new one, then modify my one field. Hmmm :(

Comment: @ColmanJ I would be grateful if you could assist with this related question in anyway https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201824/prefab-mode-only-adjusts-one-game-object-until-the-others-are-manually-selected

Answer (score 0):

just cast the loaded object to a `GameObject`

```
Object prefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(pathToPrefab, typeof(GameObject));
GameObject root = prefab as GameObject; //a prefab is also just a gameobject
FooScript = root.GetComponent<FooScript>();
root.someValue = 789;
```

don't forget to save the changes

[`EditorUtility.SetDirty(prefab)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html)

[`AssetDatabase.SaveAssets`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.SaveAssets.html)

Comment: That was the first thing I tried. root is `null` so no prefab is not a gameobject :(

Comment: @gman did you use the `AssetDatabase` class? Because in your sample code it says `Asset`. And what is the value of `root`, because if that is also `null` then your path is probably wrong.

Comment: Yea, I used the `AssetDatabase`. Sorry, `Asset.` was a typo. Also just in case it wasn't me who downvoted your answer. I updated the question.

Comment: Do I need to call `AssetDatabase.SaveAssets`? or just the user just pick "Save Project" or some such thing. The docs don't seem to say

Comment: If the user saves the project then you don't need to call the saveassets

Answer (score 0):

you need to load a GameObject like this :

```
 string prefabPath = "Assets/demo1/Resources/GameObject.prefab";
    Object prefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(prefabPath);
```

Don't forget the suffix name