# How to update a prefab property from editor script and have the instances get the updates?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a follow up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785607/how-to-edit-a-monobehaviours-properties-on-a-prefab-in-the-unityeditor-from-scr)

Assume I have a simple MonoBehaviour

```
public class FooScript : MonoBehaviour {
  public int someValue = 0;
  public int otherValue = 0;
}
```

I put that on an empty GameObject then drag the GameObject to the Project to create a prefab.

If I select the prefab and edit `someValue` then if I go to the instance still in the scene I see `someValue` is updated.

If I edit `someValue` on the instance then update `someValue` on the prefab `someValue` is *NOT* updated on the instance but if I update `otherValue` on the prefab it does update on the instance. In other words each instance property has it's own flag on if it has been modified from the source prefab or not.

But, if I make an editor script and lookup `FooScript` on the prefab and set `someValue` the instance is *NOT* updated, only the prefab. I want it to act exactly as if I had done it manually in the editor. In other words, if the instance property has been edited by the user don't update. If instance property has not been edited do update.

The question is what's the correct way to do that? Looking at [`PrefabUtilily`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.html) there doesn't appear to be a `ApplyPropertiesFromSourcePrefabOnAllUnmodifiedInstancePropreties` function.

The only solution I can think of sounds **EXTREMELY** convoluted. I'd have to

1. find all instances (walk the entire hierarchy, not sure what happens in unloaded scenes)
2. for each instance record the modifications are on it by calling `PrefabUtility.GetPropertyModifications` and storing the results in some `Dictionary<GameObject, PropertyModifications[]>`. (lots of memory)
3. Apply my change to the prefab.
4. Then, for every instance that doesn't have a modification to the field I'm updating update the that property on instance as well.

Is it really that convoluted or is there some easier way?

Comment: What happens if you use `PrefabUtility.MergeAllPrefabInstances()`?

Comment: Surprisingly that seems to have worked but the docs say "*This is done automatically and you will not have to call this function manually.*" which suggests I'm supposed to do something else. Call tried calling `EditorUtilitiy.SaveDirty(prefabGameobject)`, and that also worked which seems more appropriate?

Comment: Do you mean `EditorUtility.SetDirty(Object)`? The docs for that also say that you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: Yea, that's what I meant. I don't see where it says not to call it. In fact it says "*E.g. if you modify a **prefab's** MonoBehaviour or ScriptableObject variables, you must tell Unity that the value has changed.*"

Comment: To quote the doc: ''Prior to Unity 5.3, this was the primary method of marking objects as dirty. From 5.3 onwards, with the introduction of Multi-Scene Editing, this function should no-longer be used for modifying objects in scenes. Instead, you should use Undo.RecordObject prior to making changes to the object. This will mark the object's scene as dirty and provide an undo entry in the editor.''

Comment: In my case "PrefabUtility.MergeAllPrefabInstances()" was the answer. Thank you @IsaacvanBakel !!!

I am modifying the values on the actual target instances instead of serializedObject. Because of this reason, I had to update all prefab instances when I modify a value on the prefab itself.

It would be automatic if I would use serializedObject but I can't use it for other reasons.

Comment: @IsaacvanBakel I am having a similar issue, I would really appreciate your help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201824/prefab-mode-only-adjusts-one-game-object-until-the-others-are-manually-selected

Answer (score 1):

From a Documentation browse, it looks like Unity expects you to use `Undo.RecordObject(Object objectToUndo, string name)` in code before you modify a property on the prefab, which will also have the benefit of creating an Undo step in Unity itself so that you can revert any changes.

You can use `EditorUtility.SetDirty(Object)`, but only if you don't want to create an Undo step, and the Unity docs specifically recommend against it.

Comment: from the docs it seems like `EditorUtility.SetDirty` fits my exact use case. I'm  not modifying an object in the scene, I'm modifying a prefab that's in the AssetDatabase not in the scene. Just like a normal prefab mod behaviors there should be no undo to the instances when the prefab itself changes.